# Configuring a remote Git repository

Tags: php, macos, git

I'm new to Git, but already enjoying and reaping the benefits. However, I need to move things along.

I have Git running on my Mac, and — just so you know precisely — I'm using Coda 2 and the Github client for the Mac.

I have access to a server which has two accounts: 1. live (accessible via www.domain.com), and; 2. developer (accessible via d.domain.com).

I'd like to:

1. have the changes I'm making to a specific web application project
   (written in PHP, using MySQL) reflected on the developer account for
   the client to approve, and then;
2. finally upload to the live account afterwards.

As it stands, after much reading of [Chapter 4 of the Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server), I'm none the wiser.

While I'm a developer, I very rarely get involved hands-on in networking, terminals, or those kinds of things; I typically use cPanel and WHM.

So I'm looking for something simple to guide me through the process, certainly simpler than the aforementioned, which makes hardly any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a local Git repo with two Remote (developer domain and live domain):

```
git remote add dev http://d.domain.com/path/to/repo
git remote add live http://domain.com/path/to/repo
```

When you want to push your master branch to dev do:

```
git push dev master
```

and if you are ready to go live:

```
git pull dev master
git push live master
```

Comment: I'm very much at the beginning, here. Where would I be typing these commands?

Comment: @WayneSmallman, You'd type these commands on your Mac, from your Terminal. You can find online resources to help you with this [here](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-mac.html), [here](http://www.petermac.com/setup-git-local-and-remote-repositories/), and [here](http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/git/git.html).

Comment: @Danny I presently have versions of this project on those servers. What would happen to them if I ran these commands?

Comment: Adding your server repositories as remotes on your mac won't do anything to the remote repositories.  The only time your remote repositories would change is when you would push to them, e.g. `git push [remote name] [local branch name]`.

Comment: @Danny Am I able to use the root directory for the Repositories?

Comment: @WayneSmallman, you should use the root of the web application project for the root of the repository on each machine, development and production, respectively.  If you were asking about the root directories of the servers themselves, well, you _could_ do that if you wanted to, but it's a **really** **bad** **idea**.

Comment: @Danny, I only have access to the root directory for the account itself. Usually, web documents are to be found in "public_html", which is where the application itself is also to be found.

So in this instance, the Git directory would be stored along side the application files and folders in "public_html", yes?